# How to refresh a page on "route ionic browser build"?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4, ionic-native

I build my project on IONIC (version 6.10.0)

1. ionic cordova build browser --prod
2. ionic cordova run browser

My project starts,

[image]

but when I refresh the page, then I have the following error:

[image]

How can I fix this? The routes are however well configured:

[image]

My routing code :

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    // english
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'support',
    loadChildren: () => import('./support/support.module').then( m => m.SupportPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'user-profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('./user-profile/user-profile.module').then( m => m.UserProfilePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'choose-destination',
    loadChildren: () => import('./choose-destination/choose-destination.module').then( m => m.ChooseDestinationPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'become-guide',
    loadChildren: () => import('./become-guide/become-guide.module').then( m => m.BecomeGuidePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'selection-guide',
    loadChildren: () => import('./selection-guide/selection-guide.module').then( m => m.SelectionGuidePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'guide-form',
    loadChildren: () => import('./guide-form/guide-form.module').then( m => m.GuideFormPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'form-sent',
    loadChildren: () => import('./form-sent/form-sent.module').then( m => m.FormSentPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'ticket-sent',
    loadChildren: () => import('./ticket-sent/ticket-sent.module').then( m => m.TicketSentPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'profile-guide',
    loadChildren: () => import('./profile-guide/profile-guide.module').then( m => m.ProfileGuidePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'edit-profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('./edit-profile/edit-profile.module').then( m => m.EditProfilePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'edit-guide-profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('./edit-guide-profile/edit-guide-profile.module').then( m => m.EditGuideProfilePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'sign-in',
    loadChildren: () => import('./sign-in/sign-in.module').then( m => m.SignInPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'sign-up',
    loadChildren: () => import('./sign-up/sign-up.module').then( m => m.SignUpPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'payment',
    loadChildren: () => import('./payment/payment.module').then( m => m.PaymentPageModule)
  },
  // French
  {
    path: 'accueil',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
    // Chinois
  {
    path: '家',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Here is my routing code, maybe I forgot to add something!

Thanks for your help !

Comment: This is not the tabs routing. Please paste all you routing config as text in your quesiton.

Comment: You can see bellow I added

Comment: Please post in your question, you can edit it. You should only post an answer if you find the solution to your own question.

Comment: It's good now ?

Comment: Yes it's better but I still can't see the tabs routing, which is probably the most important according to your question.